# Prove that singletons in a Hausdorff space are closed.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $S$ be a Hausdorff topological space. If $p\in S$, I need to show that $\{p\}$ (the set containing only the element $p$) is closed. I was hoping to get some feedback on the proof attempt I have written below.

Comment: Singletons are closed in any $T_1$ space, which is weaker than Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

I must establish that $S\setminus \{p\}$ is open. A set is called Haussdorff if two distinct points have disjoint neighborhoods (i.e. for $q,p\in S$ there exist neighborhoods $U_p$ of $p$ and $U_q$ of $q$ such that $U_p\cap U_q = \emptyset$).

Therefore, let $q\in S\setminus \{p\}$ be arbitrary. Then there exists an open neighborhood $U_q$ and a neighborhood $U_p$ such that $U_p\cap U_q=\emptyset$. Hence $U_q \subset S\setminus \{p\}$. Therefore, since $q\in U_q$ for every $q$,
\begin{align}
S\setminus \{p\} \subseteq \bigcup_{q \in S\setminus \{p\} } U_q
\end{align}
and since $U_q\subset S\setminus \{p\}$ for every $q$,
\begin{align}
\bigcup_{q \in S\setminus \{p\} } U_q \subseteq S\setminus \{p\}
\end{align}
thereby establishing
\begin{align}
\bigcup_{q \in S\setminus \{p\} } U_q = S\setminus \{p\}
\end{align}
But $U_q$ is open and the union of open sets is open. Hence $S\setminus \{p\}$ is open.

Comment: From what you've said, it's immediate that $$\begin{align}
S\setminus \{p\} \supseteq \bigcup_{q \in S\setminus \{p\} } U_q.
\end{align}.$$ Justifying the reverse inclusion is trivial, which completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point to be clear about and which justifies the set equality. I've edited my proof.

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: It's not a set that is called Hausdorff, it's a topology/set endowed with a topology/topological space.

Comment: +1. Perhaps more simply, let $T$ be the family of all open sets that do not have $p$ as a member. Obviously $\cup T$ is open and $\cup T\subset S\setminus \{p\}.$ And we have  $\cup T\supset S\setminus \{p\}$ because if $q\in   S\setminus \{p\}$ then there exists $t\in T $ with $q\in T$, so $q\in\cup T$.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's answer is fine, but (as written) heavily dependent on Choice (AC).

This can easily be avoided, if $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a Hausdorff space:

let $\mathcal{U}=\{U \in \mathcal{U}\mid p \notin U\}$ and note that $\bigcup{U}$ also does not contain $p$, so that $$\bigcup \mathcal{U}\subseteq X\setminus\{p\}$$  and the reverse inclusion holds because if $q \in X\setminus \{p\}$ we get $U_q$ and $U_p$ open and disjoint neighbourhoods so that $U_q \in \mathcal{U}$ and $p \notin U_q$ (to get an open set $U_q$ like that, $T_1$ is enough, and the extra $U_p$ from Hausdorffness is "overkill") and so $$q \in U_q \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{U}$$ showing the other inclusion, as $q \in X\setminus\{p\}$ was arbitrary. We now get that $X\setminus\{p\}$ is open without the heavy use of choice.